# Email Sending Issue with CodeIgniter on nginx server

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, nginx, openssl, php-openssl

I have shifted my client management system to a new server but after that, emails notifications are not working anymore. The new server is running nginx and this is the error I'm getting in the logs. OpenSSL is updated and installed on the server.

Normal PHPMails are working but they always go to the spam/junk folder so I'm using ZohoMail for this purpose. On the previous apache server, it was running fine.

The same case is happening with WordPress installation as well. Please guide me on this issue so I can better communicate with my server vendor.

```
ERROR - 2022-04-08 05:12:16 --> Email: sendWithSmtp throwed fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
ERROR - 2022-04-08 05:12:16 --> Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.<br /><pre>Date: Fri, 8 Apr 2022 05:12:16 -0500
From: &quot;Smart Portal&quot; &lt;noreply@email.com&gt;
Return-Path: &lt;noreply@email.com&gt;
To: my@email.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Test=20message?=
Reply-To: &lt;noreply@email.com&gt;
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
X-Sender: noreply@email.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: &lt;62500a803c12f0.84020712@email.com&gt;
Mime-Version: 1.0
```

Comment: You might have self-signed ssl certificate on server you're trying to connect with `fsockopen()`. So you need to switch off certificate checking (actually, not good idea), or use some valid certificate, for example from `letsencrypt`.

Comment: The domain on which I'm running the script for testing have SSL installed. It's not self-signed but on the server IP address, there is no SSL.

Comment: What server you connect to with `fsockopen` then?